# JAXB Default value

Tags: java, jaxb

I am new into JAXB. I am trying to unmarshall a Foo object using JAXB. However, the default value is not set. Please tell me what am I doing wrong

```
public class TestJAXBDefault{
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
    public static class Foo {
        @XmlElement(defaultValue = "Hello")
        protected String bar;
    }

    @Test
    public void testDefaultValue() {
        Foo foo = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader("<foo></foo>"), Foo.class);
        Assert.assertNotNull(foo.bar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mapped the field Foo.bar to a XML element (by using @XmlElement).
When unmarshalling a document the *value* of the bar field will be set to the *content* of the bar element. The default value specified in the annotation is used when the bar element is present but empty. If it is missing it will be *null*.

```
<foo></foo>               -> Foo.bar is null
<foo><bar/></foo>         -> Foo.bar is "Hello"
<foo><bar></bar></foo>    -> Foo.bar is "Hello"
<foo><bar>baz</bar></foo> -> Foo.bar is "baz"
```